# using selenium to simulate ends-with

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

From what I heave read, there used to be an xpath selector "ends-with" so *ends-with(@id,':table')* would match something with an id of 'a1:table', 'b1:this:that:table', etc, but not "a1:table:b1'.  But they removed it.

You can write some method using substring and calculating the length, which I have done, but this can be a chore.

Is there any way using Java and Selenium to write your own selector methods?  Like

*define ends-with(x, y) {substring(@x, string-length(@x) - string-length(y)) }*

or something like that (whatever it would be)?  Or is there not a way to create user-defined methods?  And why did they remove ends-with anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify where have you read it? It is working fine for me in WebDriver, you could ether use xpath or css, obviously **ends-with(@id,':table')** would not work with **a1:table:b1**, since the ending is different.

Instead you should anchor it let say to **div** container(or whatever you have in a DOM) and look for contains

Here is how it would look like using **CSS**:

```
div[id*=':table']
```

And here snippet for **XPATH**:

```
//div[contains(@id,':table')]
```

In case you still want to try ends, here is the **CSS**:

```
div[id$=':table']
```

And **XPATH**:

```
//div[ends-with(@id,':table')]
```

Comment: I read it in a separate item and when I tried it it complained (ends-with)